# Laravel model factories not seen my application

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I am trying to use Model Factories to generate some data while I work on an App. I have created the data which I can see in the database, however, when searching with tinker it can't find anything.

I have manually added an entry using Sequel Pro and Tinker can find that. What am I doing wrong?

So, for example:

id 25 was inserted by the model factory

id 26 was manually inserted by myself

`$c = App\Models\Contact::find(25);` retruns `null`

`$c = App\Models\Contact::find(26);` retruns the correct record

Comment: Probably a silly question, but does Contact with ID 25 exist in the DB?

Comment: Yeah, that's what's weird, both show in the database

Comment: Can you include the code of model factory as well as your model?

Comment: From Sequal Pro, can you share Insert query. (Select records and right click on records, there should be an option to copy Insert SQL)

Comment: We will need to see both the model factory and the seeder please.

Comment: Did you not just forgot to call save in your factory?

Comment: any chance you are filling the deleted_at field in you Factory ?

Comment: Where is your model factory code? Where is the code that you're using to call the model factory? This question is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be in the way that you are creating your models using the Model Factories.

Try to use the method `->create()` instead of `->make()` on you model creation.

Answer (score 1):

Its strange, Basically `$c = App\Models\Contact::find(25);`, And

`$c = App\Models\Contact::find(26);`

are same for `PHP`, `Apache`, `Mysql/MariaDB`, It doesn't make any sense. But any way there are a few ways to check it out !

- Restart your local server `lamp/wamp/xampp/mamp`.
- Stop your `php artisan serve` and restart it.
- Review your model factories.
- Check DB table for id `25`. Remove views
  cacahe `php artisan view:clear`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Possibilities !